# AWS CodeStar code not propagated to the website

Tags: spring-boot, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit, aws-codestar

I have a AWS CodeStar Java Web application. I have a Route 53 domain which links to this application. Until yesterday, everything was working fine.

Yesterday, I was adding some new features and pushing them to the CodeStar repository. I didn't notice that four commits failed to build due to one issue. Today I noticed the failed builds and posted a new commit that fixes the issue. The commit was built and successfully deployed.

The problem is that the changes that I did in the commits that failed to build are not propagated to the web app. I can't see them on my website. I can open Developer tools and see that the source code is like it was before my changes.

**BUT** when I look at the code in AWS CodeCommit, all the changes are there. Included the changes I did in the commit that failed to build. The code is complete the same way I have it in my local machine.

What is the problem here? Why are the changes not propagated to the website if I can see them in CodeCommit? Do the failed builds have some negative effect here? What should I do to get my changes to my web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out what the issue is, but I just created a new CodeStar project, copied the code from the old project to the new project and continued onwards with the new (working) project.